# Executing python script with various modes

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a data pipeline in python with around 7 or 8 modes. Basically the data pipeline will be calling many class. For simplicity, I have created a simple test script ((pseudo code))as below. But every function is getting imported from a class.
Some modes/tasks are independent steps and few can be combined and make as a datapipeline.

For example test_flow is an independant workflow. create_flow and monitor_flow can be called as independant tasks or sometimes can be called together also.

Is there a better way to design the pipeline as there are about 8 modes and I feel the design(calling --modes as below) is bit clumsy. Please let me know if there are any other elegant ways. Thanks.

```
def test_flow:
    print(test_flow)

def create_flow:
    print(create_flow)
    
def monitor_flow:
    print(monitor_flow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if args.mode == "test_flow":
        test_flow
    if args.mode == "create_flow":
        create_flow
    if args.mode == "monitor_flow":
        monitor_flow
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is full of syntax errors!

I would suggest something like this, but you probably would want to ensure further that only certain functions are reachable via the command line:

```
import sys

def test_flow():
    print("called test_flow")

def create_flow():
    print("called create_flow")
    
def monitor_flow():
    print("called monitor_flow")

def main(argv):
    if len(argv)>1:
        specifiedCall = globals()[argv[1]]
        if specifiedCall:
            specifiedCall()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had posted only pseudo code.